# Displaying a div without it shifting the following elements

Tags: html, css

Is there a css property that I can apply to the div containing the error message so that it can be displayed without it shifting the following elements as shown in this picture :

[image: picture]

This is my html code :

```
        <div class="child">
            <label for="signInName">Adresse courriel</label>
            <input id="signInName" type="text"></input> 
            <div class="error itemLevel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
                <p>ce courriel est invalide</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
            <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
            <input id="password" type="text"></input>   
            <div class="error itemLevel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
                <p>Entrez votre mot de passe</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) property

The visibility CSS property shows or hides an element without changing the layout of a document.

Use `line-height: 32px;` to set the height of the message which indeed will set the gap between two inputs.

**You can either toggle the inline style**

```js
function showErrors() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.error.itemLevel').forEach((node) => node.style.visibility = "visible");
}
```

```css
.itemLevel {
  line-height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="child">
    <label for="signInName">Adresse courriel</label>
    <input id="signInName" type="text"></input>
    <div class="error itemLevel" aria-hidden="false" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <p>ce courriel est invalide</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="child">
    <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
    <input id="password" type="text"></input>
    <div class="error itemLevel" aria-hidden="false" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <p>Entrez votre mot de passe</p>
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="showErrors()">Show Errors</button>
```

**OR You can toggle the class of the element using [`DOMTokenList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle)**

```js
function showErrors() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.error.itemLevel').forEach((node) => node.classList.toggle("hidden"));
}
```

```css
.itemLevel {
  line-height: 32px;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="child">
    <label for="signInName">Adresse courriel</label>
    <input id="signInName" type="text"></input>
    <div class="error itemLevel hidden" aria-hidden="false">
        <p>ce courriel est invalide</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="child">
    <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
    <input id="password" type="text"></input>
    <div class="error itemLevel hidden" aria-hidden="false">
        <p>Entrez votre mot de passe</p>
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="showErrors()">Show Errors</button>
```

Comment: But how to keep 32px between the input text and the next label what ever if the error message is visible or hidden?

Comment: Height property of error message should be equal to 32px. Isn’t it?

Comment: Use `line-height: 32px;` to set the height of the message which indeed will set the gap between two inputs. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I’ll try it tomorrow and give you a feedback

Comment: Please don't recommend inline styles. Instead, toggle a CSS class on the element.

Comment: @connexo got it and updated the answer.